# Unable to install ruby using rvm due to mac port issues

Tags: ruby, rvm, macports

I am trying to install ruby 1.9.2 or latest to work with cupertino gems

In order to install ruby, i have install 3rd party tool(RVM)
I am able to install rvm, However to install ruby, i am getting macport errors

I tried to resolve it using existing stackoverflow question, but it does not aid me clearly in resolving the issue

Steps which i followed are:
Installed rvm from get.rvm.io

activated rvm using below command:

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Now i am trying to install ruby 1.9.2 using following command:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
```

it fails with following error

```
*BLR4AUTOMATION2:ruby-1.9.2-p320 admin$ rvm install 2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation.
Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies. Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Password:
DEBUG: Copying /Users/admin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: 
Connection refused (61) rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9] 
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs 
Exit code: 10 
DEBUG: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
    while executing "macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] 
base_updated" 
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: 
Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.*
```

I have tried to follow several thread related to it, but it did not work for me:

1. http://samkhan13.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/make-macports-work-behind-proxy
2. synching macports using tarballs and other sources
3. Tried to uninstall macports from my mac and reinstall, but that also make no use
4. Reinstall latest xcode with cli

I have uploaded the console logs at below location:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l_OFbE5d0tliKdnU_gF6Bil75Ek7wJb58h7Da_JTXdQ/edit?usp=sharing

At the same time i am able to install the ruby in my other mac machines but not on build machine
Can any one please help me in setting up ruby(1.9.2 or higher) using rvm or with other ways.

Thanks in advance!!
kishan

Comment: this problem can be limited to failing `port selfupdate`

Comment: I've had a lot more luck with rbenv on Mac OS X. But I also use brew, not port.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the internet ports are available in your router, I tried in college (tons of ports closed) and got the same problem, try again in my house with less locked ports and worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you can run

```
sudo /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
```

when you find proper flags (proxy!) then you can make sure macports will use them with `rsync_options` from [macports.conf](http://guide.macports.org/#internals.configuration-files.macports-conf)